# Using Template in struct in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am learning lambda expression in C++11x, i googled for the same and come across below code snippet where template typename used as a inheritance.

Say,

```
    template< class T >
    struct MyType : T {
            ....
```

When i complied the code it doesn't give any error. But when i tried to create an instance for the *struct MyType* it resulted in error.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template< class T >
struct MyType : T {
  static const auto data = 0;
  static const size_t erm = sizeof(data);
};


int main()
{
  struct MyType<int> my;
  std::cout<<"\n test ";
  return 0;
 }
```

Error while compiling the above code:

```
    In instantiation of 'struct MyType<int>': 
    15:22: required from here    
    6:8: error: base type 'int' fails to be a struct or class type In function 'int main()': 
    15:22: warning: unused variable 'my' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Please add some light on the same. Why compilation gives error on instantiating the struct? on the other hand Why declaration doesn't give any error?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The type parameter is used as the base class for your type. `int` isn't a class and you can't inherit from it. You need another struct (or class) to be your base. I think the error mesage _base type `int` fails to be a struct or class_ is pretty clear ...

Answer (score 4):

> Why compilation gives error on instantiating the struct? on the other
>   hand Why declaration doesn't give any error?

That is because strictly speaking a template declaration is not code. Only when you instantiate it with concrete template parameters the compiler turns the template into "real" code. You dont get an error on the template declaration, because for any struct or class type your template is fine. Only when a template is ill-formed for any template parameter the compiler will complain before you instantiate it. E.g. this

```
template <typename T> 
void foo () { asdf(); }
```

will result in an error (provided there is no `asdf` in scope):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘void foo()’: 
prog.cpp:5:20: error: there are no arguments to ‘asdf’ that depend on a 
template parameter, so a declaration of ‘asdf’ must be available    
[-fpermissive]  void foo () { asdf(); }
```

but this one

```
template <typename T>
void foo() { T::asdf(); }
```

will not, because there can be a `T` that will result in the template being well-formed. Only when you instantiate it with a `T` that has no `T::asdf()` you will get an error.

Answer (score 3):

I think the compiler gives a pretty good explanation. In short, you cannot derive from fundamental types like `int`.

The declaration itself:

```
template< class T >
struct MyType : T {
  static const auto data = 0;
  static const size_t erm = sizeof(data);
};
```

is absolutely valid. So the compiler does not complain about it.

But when it comes to instantiation of `MyType<T>` with `T = int` the compiler tries to generate the code which, generally speaking, looks like this:

```
struct MyType : int {
  static const auto data = 0;
  static const size_t erm = sizeof(data);
};
```

which is not valid *C++* because `MyType` tries to inherit from `int`.

Answer (score 0):

- The problem is that substituting `T`  with the actual type you had passed `struct MyType<int> my;` became:

  `struct MyType : int`

You can see that why this is not valid. You cannot inherit from something which is not a **class**. `int` is a *simple* built-in type.

There are a bunch of reason why this is not possible, but in my opinions all go down to the fact that *Inheritance*, *polymorphism* and *encapsulation* do not apply to built-in fundamental types. They don't have method table, so you cannot override them ...

The compiler already gives you a good error message:

`clang++` is probably clearer saying

```
test.cpp:9:17: error: base specifier must name a class
struct MyType : T {
```

while `icpc`

```
test.cpp(9): error: not a class or struct name
  struct MyType : T
```